# Is it possible to combine arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to merge the contents of all existing arrays, if the key is already in use - then nothing, and if not - then it must be added from other arrays, but with an empty value

```
  array(3) {
      [0]=>
            array(4) {
              ["attributes_3_ru-ru"] => "10"
              ["attributes_3_en-gb"] => "100"
              ["attributes_4_en-gb"] => "2222"
              ["attributes_4_ru-ru"] => ""
            }
      [1]=>
            array(2) {
              ["attributes_6_ru-ru"] => "10"
              ["attributes_6_en-gb"] => "100"
            }
        }
      [2]=>
            array(2) {
              ["attributes_4_ru-ru"] => "10"
              ["attributes_4_en-gb"] => "100"
            }
            ...n
    }
```

output is something like this

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
        array(4) {
          ["attributes_3_ru-ru"] => "10"
          ["attributes_3_en-gb"] => "100"
          ["attributes_4_en-gb"] => "2222"
          ["attributes_4_ru-ru"] => ""
          ["attributes_6_ru-ru"] => ""
          ["attributes_6_en-gb"] => ""
        }
  [1]=>
        array(2) {
          ["attributes_6_ru-ru"] => "10"
          ["attributes_6_en-gb"] => "100"
          ["attributes_3_ru-ru"] => ""
          ["attributes_3_en-gb"] => ""
          ["attributes_4_en-gb"] => ""
          ["attributes_4_ru-ru"] => ""
        }
    }
  [2]=>
        array(2) {
          ["attributes_4_ru-ru"] => "10"
          ["attributes_4_en-gb"] => "100"
          ["attributes_6_ru-ru"] => ""
          ["attributes_6_en-gb"] => ""
          ["attributes_3_ru-ru"] => ""
          ["attributes_3_en-gb"] => ""
        }
        ...n
    }
```

Comment: That duplicate does not address this question at all. It merges multiple arrays into a single array.

Comment: it addresses it, just loop over your array of arrays and merge your arrays as required.

Comment: @Andrew I apologize. Saying it doesn't address it at all was inaccurate, or at least an overstatement. I should have said, I think it's only part of the answer, and not a big enough part to be an appropriate duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this. First, collect all the keys and create a "template" array with from that with blank values.

```
$merged = array_merge(...$arrays);
$template = array_fill_keys(array_keys($merged), '');
```

Then map that over the original array of arrays and merge each entry with the template.

```
$result = array_map(function($entry) use ($template) {
    return array_merge($template, $entry);
}, $arrays);
```

Comment: ,what is array_fill_keys and when we have to use it?

Comment: @whoami array_fill_keys takes an array and a value, and creates a new array using the input array as keys, where each key has the same single value. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use array_merge() for this.

```
$megaArray = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

Or if I'm oversimplifying your use case and for some reason you need to append data to $array3 you could use foreach() and in_array() instead. Something along the lines of the following (not tested).

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
    if(!in_array($key, $array3)){
        $array3[$key] = $value;
  }
  else{
        if($array3[$key] === ""){ // if the current array3 iteration's value is blank, use the new one
            $array3[$key] = $value;
        }
  }
}
```